# fancybox is not working with jscarousel 2

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, jcarousel

i'm having a php code used with jscarousel 2

```
http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-contentthumbnail-slder-v2-0-jscarousel-v2-0/
```

to display items from the database as a carousel and having links like this

```
<a id="addtocart" product="<?php echo $productID; ?>" href="#addDiv" >add</a>
```

and a hidden div

```
<div style="display:none">
<div id="addDiv" style="width:300px; height:250px; background-color:#969;">test</div>
</div>
```

and another link just for testing and it's not inside the carousel just like the previous one

the problem is : links inside the carousel don't show the fancybox while the other link outside the carousel shows the fancybox i've tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("a#addtocart").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
    });
$(document).on("click","a#addtocart",function(){
            $(this).fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
    });
});
});
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to do? I think the problem is, you are working with IDs. Maybe you should add the "click" event you are using to a class. Every ID may be in a html document just once, so you can just have one  element with the ID addtocart.

```
<a href="#addDiv" class="fancybox" product="<?php echo $productID; ?>">add</a>
```

Try this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("a .fancybox").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
    });

    $(document).on("click","a .fancybox", function() {
        $(this).fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
    });
});
```

When you use the dot (.) instead of the hashkey (#) you are able to use classes instead of ids.

If that does not help you, you can find an implementation of jCarousel and Fancybox right here: http://www.mccran.co.uk/examples/jcarousel/

Comment: same problem after using classes $("a.add_to_cart").fancybox(); it's not working and loading the page like this mypage.php#addDiv

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to accomplish. With this script your images should open in a fancybox after clicking on them. If this does not work, there might be an issue with the implementation of fancybox I guess. What do you want to happen after typing a URL like this `mypage.php#addDiv`?

Comment: i'm not typing a URL this URL is loading after clicking on <a href="#addDiv" class="fancybox" product="<?php echo $productID; ?>">add</a> because the fancybox doesn't load while clicking the link outside the carousel is working and showing the fancybox it's the same link inside and outside the carousel no change at all

Comment: You can find a link to an example in my answer now. Here are more examples: [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?43887-I-want-to-combine-Jcarousel-with-Fancybox), [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fancybox/1Uc6bniQ-Rc)

Answer (score 0):

the solution :
just used this code at the end of the document.ready

```
$("a.add_to_cart").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
    });
```

and worked normally but after document.ready makes it doesn't work